# URL Rewriting every URI except one?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a need to rewrite all URLs except /admin/ to index.html. How would I achieve that with .htaccess? I know I need RewriteConds and writes, but everything I have tried ends up in 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you also exclude the target. Try this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^(admin/|index\.html$) /index.html [L,R]
```